# how do i use two conditions for visible attribute inside a div

Tags: asp.net, eval, webforms

I want to use two conditions for visible inside a div

```
Visible='<%# Eval("commenter_name").ToString() == username %> || username == admin'
```

its not working. i can only use one condition. is there any way to get around this?

Comment: is username variable data coming from datasource?

Answer (score 4):

am assuming ASP.NET

try this:

concatenate the two boolean results,(as you would normally do in the c#).

```
Visible='<%# 
          Eval("commenter_name").ToString() == Eval("username").ToString() 
          || 
          Eval("username").ToString() == "admin" 
         %>'
```

alternatively, if you too many conditions to verify:

replace it with a function

```
Visible ='<%# VerifyConditions(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Id"))) %>'
```

and define VerifyConditions like this in your codebehind(.aspx.cs) page:

```
public bool VerifyConditions(int Id)
{
   string username= GetCurrentUser();
   //obtain other variables, either through the bound row, or 
   //from the db based on the Id
    //all your logics..

    return  true; //or false based on evaluation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to put your expressions within the databinding expression tags. It will work as long as the expression results in a bool

```
Visible='<%# Eval("commenter_name").ToString() == Eval("username").ToString() || Eval("username").ToString() == "admin" %>'
```